# Understanding equation 11.11 in Griffiths "introduction to electrodynamics"

Tags: electromagnetism

I am reviewing my electrodynamics and stumbled upon an approximation in Griffiths "introduction to electrodynamics" which I still don't understand after ponding on it.

My question is: How does he arrive at eq. 11.11 from the trigonometric sum in the buttom of the first attached picture? I don't understand how he arrives at equation 11.11. Below I attached the equation in question plus the section leading up to it.

The topic is electric dipole radiation.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the last picture being upside down, tried rotate it and upload it again, but it didn't resolve the issue

Comment: 1.11 seems to be a Taylor series expansion, using 11.8. Posting scans is a no-no for this site. You are expected to type the relevant equations using MathJax. See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He simply write  the development $\cos (\varepsilon )=1+o(\varepsilon )$ and $\sin (\varepsilon )=\varepsilon +o(\varepsilon )$ with $\varepsilon =\frac{\omega d}{2c}\cos (\theta )\ll 1$

Comment: i think you meant $sin(\epsilon)=\epsilon + \mathcal{o}(\epsilon^2)$.